# Typical wp_kses $allowed

Tags: wp-kses

I have a custom post textbox that I want to sanitize using `wp_kses` before I update my post meta.

I was looking for examples of common `$allowed` settings, but I have only seen this example:

```
$allowed = array(  
        'a' => array( // on allow a tags  
            'href' => array() // and those anchors can only have href attribute  
        )  
    );
```

What is a typical `wp_kses` `$allowed` setting? Can someone provide an example of what they normally filter for?

Comment: This question is out of scope for the site as there is more than one correct answer. If you narrow the scope of the question, present a usage case and ask for someone to provide you with things you should include that would be much better.

Comment: I want to have a rich text box where the user can just enter regular text, bold, links, italics...

Comment: The problem was I am looking for.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I would disagree with the solution posted by @JaredCobb, `wp_kses()` is much more flexible than the method he presented. It can strip out unwanted attributes from tags without destroying the tags themselves. For example, if the user put in `<strong class='foo'>`, `wp_kses()` would return `<strong>` if you did not allow class, whereas `strip_tags()` would remove the `<strong>` completely.

@redconservatory: The attributes you'll want to use are as follows:

```
$args = array(
    //formatting
    'strong' => array(),
    'em'     => array(),
    'b'      => array(),
    'i'      => array(),

    //links
    'a'     => array(
        'href' => array()
    )
);
```

This will allow bold and italics with no attributes, as well as anchor tags with an `href` attributes...and nothing else. It uses the whitelisting principle, which @jaredcobb rightly noted is the better way to go here.

Comment: Can't you tell strip tags what tags are allowed? http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php

Comment: Although, I can still see how wp_kses is better now that I can see how it strips out unwanted classes...

Comment: I probably didn't explain clearly... But yes, `wp_kses` allows more control than the native PHP options. I think I said that. I used the word "attributes" as well. I was saying it depends on your use case. Someone trying to protect their data from all tags would be better off using strip_tags IMHO but it's more of my preference than anything else. Cheers.

Answer (score 8):

I would start out with the same `$allowedtags` array that WordPress uses for their comments.  You can find their array in the `[wordpress directory]/wp-includes/kses.php` file.  These seem like sensible defaults to me, and a good starting point.  Here is their array...

```
$allowedtags = array(
    'a' => array(
        'href' => true,
        'title' => true,
    ),
    'abbr' => array(
        'title' => true,
    ),
    'acronym' => array(
        'title' => true,
    ),
    'b' => array(),
    'blockquote' => array(
        'cite' => true,
    ),
    'cite' => array(),
    'code' => array(),
    'del' => array(
        'datetime' => true,
    ),
    'em' => array(),
    'i' => array(),
    'q' => array(
        'cite' => true,
    ),
    'strike' => array(),
    'strong' => array(),
);
```

I would **NOT** use PHP's `strip_tags` as a replacement for `wp_kses`.

#### You should never use strip_tags to filter an unknown user's content!

I have created a quick video explaining [Why WordPress’ wp_kses() is better than PHP’s strip_tags() for security](http://mikemclin.net/wp_kses-better-php-strip_tags/).

Comment: Hello  what about &nbps

Answer (score 3):

There you go. This works both in WordPress and outside of WordPress.

```
<?php

$str = '     I am <strong>stronger</strong> and cooler every single day <aaaaa>.    ';
echo orbisius_html_util::strip_tags($str);

/**
 * Util HTML class
 * @author Svetoslav Marinov (SLAVI) | http://orbisius.com
 */
class orbisius_html_util {
    /**
     * Uses WP's wp_kses to clear some of the html tags but allow some attribs
     * usage: orbisius_html_util::strip_tags($str);
     * uses WordPress' wp_kses()
     * @param str $buffer string buffer
     * @return str cleaned up text
     */
    public static function strip_tags($buffer) {
        static $default_attribs = array(
            'id' => array(),
            'class' => array(),
            'title' => array(),
            'style' => array(),
            'data' => array(),
            'data-mce-id' => array(),
            'data-mce-style' => array(),
            'data-mce-bogus' => array(),
        );

        $allowed_tags = array(
            'div'           => $default_attribs,
            'span'          => $default_attribs,
            'p'             => $default_attribs,
            'a'             => array_merge( $default_attribs, array(
                'href' => array(),
                'target' => array('_blank', '_top'),
            ) ),
            'u'             =>  $default_attribs,
            'i'             =>  $default_attribs,
            'q'             =>  $default_attribs,
            'b'             =>  $default_attribs,
            'ul'            => $default_attribs,
            'ol'            => $default_attribs,
            'li'            => $default_attribs,
            'br'            => $default_attribs,
            'hr'            => $default_attribs,
            'strong'        => $default_attribs,
            'blockquote'    => $default_attribs,
            'del'           => $default_attribs,
            'strike'        => $default_attribs,
            'em'            => $default_attribs,
            'code'          => $default_attribs,
        );

        if (function_exists('wp_kses')) { // WP is here
            $buffer = wp_kses($buffer, $allowed_tags);
        } else {
            $tags = array();

            foreach (array_keys($allowed_tags) as $tag) {
                $tags[] = "<$tag>";
            }

            $buffer = strip_tags($buffer, join('', $tags));
        }

        $buffer = trim($buffer);

        return $buffer;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello, Mr Svetoslav, is this at this days still secure? I've been looking for a simple yet secure way to sanitize user input to my backoffice (no Wordpress).I just want to allow the use of basic html formatting such those present in your code, <b>, <I>, <u>. Do you think I can use this as strip_tags($_POST['myDoc']) or do you think I should do anything else to be safe? Thanks for help!

Comment: Hi, use my code. It checks if it's ran within WordPress context will use WP function otherwise will fallback to php strip_tags. Also it's better to use $_REQUEST rather than $_POST because at some point you may pass data as a GET parameter.

Comment: thanks for reply :-). I'm struggling with a problem now... if I paste formatted html or per example some code from sublime text 3 most of text is missing, there must be some hidden formatted code breaking the script.

Comment: could be a utf8 encoding issue

Comment: It may be, i’m cleaning up html as i’ve posted in the answer above, searching for \n, \r and so on but the problem is still there :-(. Cleaning pasted data may be a huge problem, some years ago i used copy paste to textedit to clean the copied strings, but i can’t expect my users would do the same.

Comment: What's exactly the problem?  What new lines?

Comment: Hello  what about &nbps

Answer (score 2):

I've only used `wp_kses` when I've specifically needed to allow / filter **attributes** of HTML tags (for example, I want them to be allowed to have an `<image>` tag, with a `src=""` attribute but I **don't** want them to be able to but `href=""` or `style=""` or anything else on the image tag.  In that case, `wp_kses` comes in handy because (as you can see in the example you created) you can filter down very specifically.  I've rarely used `wp_kses` though because I just find that a couple of native PHP functions (below) do the trick and are easier to understand when I look at the code several months later.

If you want to completely remove HTML tags (except maybe allow a few) then I always use [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strip-tags.php).  You can pass in a string of allowed tags (like `<p> <br> <strong>`) or whatever other harmless tags you like.  This allows the user to be able to have *some* control over formatting, if that's applicable for your use case.  I like `strip_tags` because it takes a *whitelist* approach to sanitizing your data.  (Meaning that **everything** gets stripped except what you explicitly whitelist).

If your goal is to allow them to put any HTML into the content, but you just want to show their text as they entered it (like code examples) then use [`htmlspecialchars`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.htmlspecialchars.php).  This will convert HTML characters into their encoded counterparts so you can safely output it to the page.

You might come across code using [`str_replace`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php) which "looks" for bad tags like  or  or whatever.  I really don't recommend that approach because it takes a *blacklist* approach to sanitizing data and you've got to constantly make sure your blacklist is up to date.

I guess to sum up, it depends on what your metaboxes are used for.  If you're protecting against input from users (who might be malicious) I'd recommend `strip_tags` and just allow some of the harmless tags.  If you have a good business case to really micromanage the tags and specific attributes of the user's content, `use wp_kses`.

Comment: Doesn't `wp_kses()` do everything that `strip_tags()` does and more? I'm all for keeping things simple, but I also think there's an argument for not "surprising" anyone. `wp_kses()` is "the Wordpress way", and since we're writing Wordpress code, there's an argument that it's probably the better choice. Plus, if at some point in the future, we want to whitelist certain tag/attribute combinations, using `wp_kses()` from the beginning doesn't require a refactor.

Answer (score 1):

You could also use wp_kses_post function which is used on post content and requires only data as a parameter.

More info here: http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post

Answer (score 0):

@Svetoslav Marinov

I've added this code just after $buffer = trim($buffer);

```
    $string_limpa = array(
                '<div><p><\/div>' => '<br>',
                '<div><br><\/div>'=> '<br>',
                '<div align="left"><br><\/div>' => '<br>',
                '<div align="center"><br><\/div>' => '<br>',
                '<div align="right"><br><\/div>' => '<br>',
                '<div style="text-align: left;"><br><\/div>' => '<br>',
                '<div style="text-align: center;"><br><\/div>' => '<br>',
                '<div style="text-align: right;"><br><\/div>' => '<br>',
                '<div style="text-align: justify;"><br><\/div>' => '<br>',
                'class="Apple-style-span"' => '<br>',
                '<p><br></p>' => '<br>',
                '<p><b></p>' => '<br>',
                '<p><i></p>' => '<br>',
                '<p><u></p>' => '<br>',
                '\r' => '<br>',
                '\n' => '<br>',
                '\t' => ' ',
                '\0' => ' ',
                '\x0B' => '<br>',
                '<p style="text-align: center;"><br></p>' => '<br>'
            );
    return strtr($buffer, $string_limpa);
```

to try to clean html and avoid pasted hidden characters breaking code, but it does not work, it cleans the html, but hidden characters still remain.