# How to keep specific tag from an html string?

Tags: escaping

Hello I try to keep only specific tag from an html string.

For example:

```
$allowed_tag=array('a');
$content = '<a href="#">link</a> <b>strong text</b>';
$content = prefix_remove_specific_tag($content, $allowed_tag);
echo $content
```

Will return

```
<a href="#">link</a> strong text
```

I'm sure a wp core function existe for that, but i can't find it :(

Answer (score 0):

I had to ask to finally find the solution, lol.

The [wp_kses](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses) do exactly that:

```
$allowed_tags = array(
    'a'      => array(
        'href'      => array(),
    ),
);
$content = '<a href="#">link</a> <b>strong text</b>';
$content = wp_kses($content, $allowed_tags);
```

I found the solution in [another topic](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/44764/typical-wp-kses-allowed/44773#44773)

Comment: Just keep in mind that this is the opposite of how you phrased your original question. This code will remove everything _except_ a specific tag. Not a specific tag. For example, if you only want to remove `<b>` tags, this won't work. That might be what you were always after, but I just wanted to point that out.

Comment: You're right, I edited the title to avoid confusion.